# Rendering from imported component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in the front-end but the code has become pretty large and wanted to try to split it so that all the rendering styles are done in a different component.

I tried using the map function but getting errors about map not being a function, maybe because the states that I want to pass on aren't arrays?

What I want is something like this:
Parent Component --> Pass all the states --> Child Component

Then, child component can just use this.state.value to display

Is there a good and easy approach to splitting up the code in cases like this where it's become too large? It's rendering 2 different looks depending on a condition and so that's where it started getting large.

Comment: What do your components do ? What is the state you want to share ?

Comment: This one, in particular, is just a profile page component, where there can be two different types of profiles. My App.js just routes the request to my profile component. Then from there, I want to do the verification for which type of profile to render, then render that from a different component that contains the render styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two different looks can be created as two different components, and the state of the parent components can be passed into child components as props.

In parent component you can use conditional rendering to show which ever child component you want based on the condition.

Comment: I agree with Raj, the map function is not defined because the array is undefined in the child component state. Probably this.props.value.map is defined properly.

Comment: I will try this approach and let you know where I end up, I wasn't too sure if it was props or states that I needed when calling from the child component, so that should help a lot. I'm fairly new to React so I'm still figuring out a lot of stuff as I go.